# Labeled LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation) in PyMC3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lda, topic-modeling, pymc3

I am trying to create a Labeled LDA model as described in this [paper (section 3.2)](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mausam/papers/emnlp11.pdf).

What I have so far is:

```
# settings
entityTypesSize = 100
minibatchSize = 10
entityStringsSize = 100

model = pm.Model()
with pm.Model() as model:
   alpha = pm.Gamma(alpha=0.1, beta=1, name='alpha')
   eta = pm.Gamma(alpha=0.1, beta=1, name='eta') 


   beta = pm.Dirichlet('beta', a=eta * np.ones((entityTypesSize, entityStringsSize)),
                    shape=(entityTypesSize, entityStringsSize), transform=t_stick_breaking(1e-9))

   theta = pm.Dirichlet('theta', a=alpha * np.ones((minibatchSize, entityTypesSize)),
                     shape=(minibatchSize, entityTypesSize), transform=t_stick_breaking(1e-9))


   z = pm.Multinomial('z', n=, p=)

   w = pm.Multinomial('w', n=, p=)
```

The challenge I am having is with the `z` and `w` random variables. As stated in the paper, the number of draws (n-param) should not be fixed, but depends on the number of words in an entity string. Furthermore, I need to place different probabilities (p-param), since they are sampled from the beta and theta distributions. Is it possible to have them somehow chained? If yes, can someone assist with that, please?

The same model has a alternative implementation in [HBC](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/HBC/), which can be found [here](https://github.com/aritter/twitter_nlp/blob/master/hbc/models/LDA.hier).

Thank you!!!